# Install4j - is there any way killing currently used ports?

Tags: install4j

When our installer getting failed, a rollback process is starting by default.
Because our installer involves Windows services, we use the `Optional Rollback Script` property to close and delete these services in case of a failure after their installation.

Our problem is that some processes remain assigned to some ports, a situation which leads the user to not be able to delete the installation directory without killing these ports first.

Now, in the command line, it's quite easy to locate and kill these processes with the commands:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<portNumber>
taskkill /PID <processId> /F
```

My problem is that I'm not able to run these commands through the `Run Script` action, getting their processes id's and than close them. (not matter what, I cannot get the output back)

Is there any such a build-in option in the Installer? If not, is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WinProcesses API to kill processes:

https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/windows/WinProcesses.html

As for calling netstat, you have to call

```
netstat -ano
```

with a "Run executable or batch file" action and set its "Redirect stdout" property to "To installer variable". Then you can parse the output in a "Run script" action.

Comment: Thanks.
I have difficulty running the `netstat -ano` command through the "Run executable or batch file" action and getting the output.
Do I have to define the `Working Directory` property?

Comment: No, but you have to specify the full path to netstat, i.e. `${installer:sys.system32Dir}\netstat.exe`, and `-ano` has to go into the "Arguments" property.

Comment: This is working but I cannot use the "pipe" char on the | findstr :<portNumber> to filter the output by a specific port. Adding the 2nd argument in a new line in the "Arguments" property doesn't work and the output return null.

Comment: Indeed, the pipe is not supported. You would have to parse the output yourself.

Comment: Is there any installer's full path variable to netstat in Linux as well?

Comment: No, but you can execute `/bin/sh` as the executable and pass arguments `-c` and the then a whole command line as the second argument that can call netstat from the path without the full path. In that way you can also setup a process chain with pipes.